# Sort Element in Array of Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I wish to sort the arrays by the time (which is the 3rd element). However, when I print out the result, the sequence of the array seems to have no difference.

Can I know what's the error? Thank you!

```
const events =[
  [ 1, '1230000003', '09:00:00' ],
  [ -1, '1230000003', '14:00:00' ],
  [ -1, '1110000002', '12:30:00' ],
  [ 1, '1110000002', '14:00:00' ],
  [ -1, '1110000007', '08:30:00' ],
  [ 1, '1110000007', '11:00:00' ],
  [ -1, '1110000008', '09:00:00' ],
  [ 1, '1110000008', '12:00:00' ]
]
```

This is my code:

```
 events.sort((a, b) => a[0][2] - b[0][2]);
 console.log("sorted start time",events);
```

Comment: Hm. `a[0][2]` is undefined in your case. Same as a `b[0][2]`.

Comment: @VasylMoskalov I see.. but it seems okay when i do it to other elements like `a[0][1]` and `b[0][1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `localCompare`

```js
const events =[ [ 1, '1230000003', '09:00:00' ], [ -1, '1230000003', '14:00:00' ], [ -1, '1110000002', '12:30:00' ], [ 1, '1110000002', '14:00:00' ], [ -1, '1110000007', '08:30:00' ], [ 1, '1110000007', '11:00:00' ], [ -1, '1110000008', '09:00:00' ], [ 1, '1110000008', '12:00:00' ] ]
events.sort((a, b) => a[2].localeCompare(b[2]));
console.log("sorted start time",events);
```

Comment: yes this solution works for my code! However when I run the code, may I know why this will come first  `[
    1,
    "1230000003",
    "09:00:00"
  ],` instead of this `[
    -1,
    "1110000008",
    "09:00:00"
  ],` ?

Comment: that's because since the function compares time, both values in this case are equal, and since the first value in the first array is passed first it will show first in the result does that makes since ?

Answer (score 2):

Since it is date is string , you should use the sort function as

```js
const events =[
  [ 1, '1230000003', '09:00:00' ],
  [ -1, '1230000003', '14:00:00' ],
  [ -1, '1110000002', '12:30:00' ],
  [ 1, '1110000002', '14:00:00' ],
  [ -1, '1110000007', '08:30:00' ],
  [ 1, '1110000007', '11:00:00' ],
  [ -1, '1110000008', '09:00:00' ],
  [ 1, '1110000008', '12:00:00' ]
]

events.sort((a, b) => a[2].localeCompare(b[2]));
console.log(events);
```

Comment: thanks! this actually helps! but can I know why when it comes to same timing like `[ 1,'1230000003', '09:00:00' ]` and `[ -1, '1110000008', '09:00:00' ]`, the first one will come first instead of second one, what if i want this `[ -1, '1110000008', '09:00:00' ]` to come first?

Comment: you can customize the logic to check if the field you are checking on is same , then compare based on the other one you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Change this;

```js
 events.sort((a, b) => a[0][2] - b[0][2]);
```

To this:

```js
events.sort((a, b) => a[2] > b[2] ? 1 : -1);
```

Result:

```js
[
  [-1, "1110000007", "08:30:00"],
  [-1, "1110000008", "09:00:00"],
  [1, "1230000003", "09:00:00"],
  [1, "1110000007", "11:00:00"],
  [1, "1110000008", "12:00:00"],
  [-1, "1110000002", "12:30:00"],
  [1, "1110000002", "14:00:00"],
  [-1, "1230000003", "14:00:00"]
]
```